# same colum name with different table id in mysql

Tags: mysql

tables

```
person_id   (primary key)

phs_people  (person_id,first_name,last_name)

phs_cutomers (person_id,company_name) 

phs_waiters (person_id,commission)
```

person_id is key between them.

So my question how can retrive customers firstname and last name, waiter firstname and lastname via person_id?

```
SELECT 
c.first_name AS customer_Fist_name,
c.last_name AS Customer_LastName, 
c.first_name AS WaiterFirstName, 
c.last_name AS Waiter_LastName,
invoice_number, amount_tendered, sale_time, DATE_FORMAT( sale_time, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS sale_date, phs_sales.sale_id AS sale_id, SUM( item_unit_price * quantity_purchased * ( 1 - discount_percent /100 ) ) AS amount_due
FROM (
phs_sales
)
LEFT JOIN phs_people c ON c.person_id = phs_sales.customer_id
AND person_id = phs_sales.waiter_id
JOIN phs_sales_items ON phs_sales_items.sale_id = phs_sales.sale_id
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT sale_id, SUM( payment_amount ) AS amount_tendered
FROM phs_sales_payments
WHERE payment_type <> 'Check'
GROUP BY sale_id
) AS payments ON payments.sale_id = phs_sales.sale_id
GROUP BY sale_id
ORDER BY sale_time DESC
LIMIT 25
```

if I execute this query, I get the following error:

```
customer_Fist_name NULL,Customer_LastName NULL, WaiterFirstName NULL, Waiter_LastName NULL,
```

Comment: what's the problem with your query? What error do you get? I shortly read your query - remove this part: `phs_people w ON` and use `c.person_id` in the next condition

Comment: if i remove then error LEFT JOIN phs_people c ON c.person_id = phs_sales.customer_id
AND w.person_id = phs_sales.waiter_id (#1054 - Unknown column 'w.first_name' in 'field list')
otherwise
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'w ON w.person_id = phs_sales.waiter_id JOIN phs_sales_items ON phs_sales_items' at line 19
 @Andy

Comment: Ok, your old error says exactly, that the part i advised you to remove, is faulty. The error you should look after now is the new one you got after removing the mentioned part

Comment: @Andy if i remove this line LEFT JOIN phs_people c ON c.person_id = phs_sales.customer_id
AND c.person_id = phs_sales.waiter_id.. then waiter name ,customer name showing null,null.. what would be solution of it?

Comment: you don't have to remove the whole line. The line you've written above should be correct... Please go step-by-step trough my answer and if you still get an error, please update the query and error in your question

Comment: @Andy  i updated my query check it and figure out where i'm doing wrong

Comment: `AND person_id = ...` isn't correct... use `person_id.id` (or however the field's named in your table)

Comment: And please provide your whole SQL-Sructure or create a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Can you please add the table `phs_sales_items`?

Comment: Phs_sales_items Added @Andy

Comment: waiting for you @Andy

Comment: join people twice

Comment: @Strawberry i know that, my question how i can separate both same  with ids..

Comment: Use aliases. (This is basic stuff)

Comment: @Andy link updated http://freetexthost.com/tj6nwg12t4

Comment: Thanks you , its Work for me...Appreciate your Work.  @Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do `JOIN`'s two times on the same table but with different values (customer's data and waiter's data), but you just use a `JOIN` once and give both conditions there.

To fix this, your have to `JOIN` the `phs_people`-Table twice like this:

```
...
LEFT JOIN phs_people AS c1 ON c1.person_id = phs_sales.customer_id
LEFT JOIN phs_people AS c2 ON c2.person_id = phs_sales.waiter_id
...
```

and then select the correct data like this:

```
SELECT
c1.first_name AS customer_Fist_name,
c1.last_name AS Customer_LastName,
c2.first_name AS WaiterFirstName,
c2.last_name AS Waiter_LastName,
...
```

PS: With this query, you should still get multiple `NULL`-Values, that's because half of your `phs_sales`-Table is filled with empty fields...

Comment: i did it but, customer_Fist_name NULL,Customer_LastName NULL, WaiterFirstName NULL, Waiter_LastName NULL, .what would be solution?